# Is there a workaround to getting a "User Cancelled" dialog from Resharper refactorings failed due to read-only files?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.1

I have the unortunate sitation with using a source control tool that keeps my local files read-only if they are not checked out. When I attempt to apply a refactoring such as Move to Another Namespace using Resharper 6.1.1, it fails with the dialog

[image: Resharper Recactoring Failure]

because the other files in the solution are currently read-only. Is there a fix or workaround for this? If not I'll enter it into their issue tracker.

Comment: What source control system are you using? Could you checkout all the files in your solution/project before attempting this operation?

Comment: It's Clear Case. Thankfully moving to TFS soon. Checking out the files or making them writeable is possible, but it causes Clear Case noise during the user experience, which is already painful.

Comment: I remember using Clear Case ages ago - I feel your pain :) TFS is not brilliant but at least it works well with refactoring.

Comment: I had a similar issue that was caused by the new Git tools from microsoft. I blogged about it here: http://core-techs.net/Blog/161/resharper-refactoring-failed-caused-by-visual-studio-2012-tfs-git-provider

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I would write a script to change read only property of the files.
Depending on the IDE you're using you might be able to call such script in specific events like every build (supported by Visual Studio 2010).

[Make read-only file read write from commandline windows](https://superuser.com/questions/395865/make-read-only-file-read-write-from-commandline-windows)